Why are consecutive AVX2 loads producing so many `vmovaps` operations?
I like to load several consecutive SIMD vectors and store them in a container with a size known at compile time. (That would allow me to write portable code for architectures with different register counts. For AVX2 (Arm Neon), I load 3 (4) vectors.)
When I look at the AVX2 code, I am surprised about the number of vmovaps operations.
Consider the following code:
#include <array>
#include <immintrin.h>
using InpT = const float* __restrict__;

template <size_t unroll_cout>
auto  load(InpT data, size_t index) {
    using vecs = std::array<__m256, unroll_cout>;
    alignas(32) vecs loaded;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < unroll_cout; ++i) {
        loaded[i] = _mm256_load_ps(data + index);
        index += 8;
    }
    return loaded;
}

template auto load<3ul>(InpT data, size_t index);

auto loadSingle(InpT data, size_t index) {
    auto vec = _mm256_load_ps(data + index);
    return vec;
}

For the general load operation, I see:
auto load<3ul>(float const*, unsigned long):
        mov     rax, rdi
        vmovaps ymm0, ymmword ptr [rsi + 4*rdx]
        vmovaps ymm1, ymmword ptr [rsi + 4*rdx + 32]
        vmovaps ymm2, ymmword ptr [rsi + 4*rdx + 64]
        vmovaps ymmword ptr [rdi + 64], ymm2
        vmovaps ymmword ptr [rdi + 32], ymm1
        vmovaps ymmword ptr [rdi], ymm0
        vzeroupper
        ret

Whilst loading just one value works as I expect:
loadSingle(float const*, unsigned long):
        vmovaps ymm0, ymmword ptr [rdi + 4*rsi]
        ret

Loading three consecutive vectors seems to move data in memory between two different regions.
Is the code for load<3> optimal? If not, how can I improve it?

Your 3 element vector can only be returned in memory hence the stores. You can't change that if you wish to adhere to calling convention.

Thanks, @Jester!  Can you elaborate a bit on the calling convention (maybe turn it into an answer?)? Second (if you don't mind): Can I thus expect only three vmovaps in inlined code?

Presumably this will be part of a larger data processing function, right? There it will be inlined and the whole issue disappears

Regarding the calling convention, see for example How are oversized struct returned on the stack?.

Thanks, @Homer512! Indeed, in the actual data processing code the functions are inlined. I saw many vmovaps in the whole program and tried to isolate the issue, so I developed the question above. But maybe I'm on the wrong track then. Thanks also for the info about the calling convention.
